# Not getting how to prove reverse hypothesis.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, logic, definition, group-actions

This is a theorem from Dummit & Foote text-

> Let $G$ be  a group acting on the non-empty set $A$.The relation on $A$ defined by
>
> $a \sim b$ **iff** $a=g.b$ for some $g \in G$
>
> is an equivalence relation.

I've shown that  '$\sim$' is an equivalence relation.
But as this theorem is a **bi-implication** statement,i' don't know how to prove **reverse hypothesis** even i'm not getting WHAT  is it?

Need help in this.

Any suggestions are heartly welcome.

thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no equivalence (or 'bi-implication'), only the following implication:

> **If** $G$ is a group acting on a non-empty set $A$, **then** the relation $\sim$ on $A$ defined by
>   $$a\sim b\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad (\exists g\in G)(a=gb),$$
>   is an equivalence relation.

The '**iff**' in your question only serves to define the relation on $A$.

Comment: :thanks a lot!!